# Database content not retrieved in the exported SWF and published HTML

Tags: mysql, database, actionscript-3, flash

I have this problem that when i am running my project in Flash cs6 using ctrl+enter, the project is ok, the flash player is retrieving the files from mysql database. but when i run the independent swf file outside, there is no retrieval happening. the text box that suppose to be showing the retrieved data is empty. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the published html from an actual page in the browser and not from the local file system.

Just make sure that the URL doesn't start with file:///

You must be having a security sandbox error, but you probably don't have the Debugger version of the Flash Player, so it's not telling you anything.

Just go to http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html and choose the proper one for your operating system and browser.

If you STILL want to run the files from your local file system, you can have a look at Flash Player's Global Configuration, to give access to the files/directories you want. Just right click on your swf file in the browser, and when the Menu opens, select Global Configuration.

The reason it is working when running inside Flash CS6 is that the player has less security restrictions in there.

Let me know if you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you! though i edited the global configuration settings, still no good. I got it worked when i put the published html file in the xampp folder and run it in a browser but the swf file is not retrieving the data when i play it in the flash player. anyway, it's fine for now. thank you very much sir!